# Chai: TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined

Tags: node.js, chai, chai-http

I'm getting started with chai-HTTP testing and I don't really know why I keep getting

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with the code? I have tried some solutions I have found around here but none of them seem to work. I get either can not read "adress" or app.adress is not a function is delete the .default from the server.

**Here's the test file: user.test.js**

```
let chai = require('chai');
let chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const server = require("../server").default;

chai.use(chaiHttp);

const user = require("../routes/user.routes");


describe('get/Users', () => {
    it('should return status 200', (done) => {
        chai.request(server)
            .get('/users/findAll')
            .end(function (err, res) {
                expect(res).to.have.status(200);
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

**Here's the server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");

const db = require("./config/database");

//environment variables
require("dotenv").config();

//Initialization
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json()); //parse json


//routes
const router = require("./routes/router");
app.use("/", router);

//starts listening
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server running on", port);
});
```

Comment: And where have you used `.address`? I can't find that into the code.

Comment: That's the thing I don't have any .adress nor any variable name address. And when I execute the server it runs perfectly. SO that it is why I'm not sure what it's happening here

Comment: And how is your controller for `/user/findAll`? Somewhere over the project should be a variable named `address`.

Comment: What do you export from `server.js`? Show the code.